# Rotated div to be full height and full half side of the screen no matter the screen size

Tags: html, css

I want the blue div to fill the right side of the screen. Given that the div is rotated, on large screens the top corner will appear unless I set the width and height to be 1000%. I have to deal with really large screens.

What will be the solution to not insert high values there? Thanks!

```css
.background {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: -10%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa9tgozh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

For this particular sort of solution, I'd suggest using a background-image with linear-gradient dictating the two colors, while degree and percentages shape their border. Here's an example:

```
.diagonal-color-div{
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(10deg, #fff 50%, #004E95 50%);
  min-height: 1080px;
}
```

Here's the above code demonstrated live: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKYmdv

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution, but 1) this will fill in the left side of the screen. I have some text there. 2) the min-height will have present some issues. what if the screen is less than that height?

Comment: No problem! So, for that I would recommend using 'height: 100vh;'. What that does is enforce that the div will be the height of the viewport (the height of the user's screen). You'll also want to set a min-height to ensure that things don't get sloppy if a user has a very short viewport (such as when a smartphone is in landscape).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.background {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skew(10deg);
}

.background2 {
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 110%;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -10%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <div class="background">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="background2">

</div>
```

Comment: I m not sure if it works for you. please check it out once. Thanks